# Trigger a macro on new sheet addition

Tags: excel, vba

I have vba code for insert sheet button click

```
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
```

How to transform it to

```
IF Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet THEN {Statement}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Are you asking about responding to the addition of a new sheet?  If Yes then look at the `Workbook_NewSheet` event.

Comment: You can use with statement after creation of sheet.

Comment: If click insert sheet then run macro

Comment: You can run any code you like following the call to `Sheets.Add`, so it's not clear what the real problem is.

Comment: I just want when i click add new sheet then macro auto run but i cant write this condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Workbook.NewSheet` event.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.newsheet

Insert it behind the `ThisWorkBook` object.

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    'some code
End Sub
```